# Display Buffer in Other Window in Recent Emacs

Tags: emacs, window, buffer

How do I programmatically display a buffer in a window `other than the current`, similar to the behaviour of Emacs' grep `next-error`. I want this to work in the most recent Emacs 24.1. Note that this logic recently was modified in Emacs trunk and merged into a single function `display-buffer` with quite complicated calling semantics. I find it hard to figure out how use `display-buffer` even after having read the help on it several times. Why isn't there a wrapper function for this such as `display-buffer-other-window`?

Answer (score 6):

The lengthy docstring to `display-buffer` includes the following:

> The ACTION argument to `display-buffer' can also have a non-nil
>   and non-list value.  This means to display the buffer in a window
>   other than the selected one, even if it is already displayed in
>   the selected window.  If called interactively with a prefix
>   argument, ACTION is t.

Therefore to display a specified buffer in a window other than the current, you can use:

```el
(display-buffer BUFFER-OR-NAME t)
```

Comment: How does this differ in behaviour from `(pop-to-buffer BUFFER 'other-window)`?

Comment: `display-buffer` does not select the window. `pop-to-buffer` calls display-buffer, and then selects the window. Note that the `'other-window` ACTION is identical to using `t` (i.e. "a non-nil and non-list value"), and does not result in the `other-window` function being used to determine the window, as it might look; it just causes `inhibit-same-window` to be set.

Answer (score 3):

The Emacs sources gave me the answer

```
(pop-to-buffer BUFFER 'other-window)
```

Answer (score 3):

And the wrapper exists, BTW, it's called `switch-to-buffer-other-window`.